# Rhie--Chow interpolation on PDE level

Tags: fluid-dynamics, reference-request, navier-stokes

The Rhie--Chow [[1](https://arc.aiaa.org/doi/abs/10.2514/3.8284)] interpolation seems to be a standard tool in the Finite-Volume discretization of incompressible flows.

It is commonly defined on the discrete level [[2](http://www.tfd.chalmers.se/~lada/comp_fluid_dynamics/postscript_files/chapter_rhie.pdf)].

In the lecture notes [[3](http://www.tfd.chalmers.se/~lada/comp_fluid_dynamics/lecture_notes.html)] -- Chapter 6, page 56 [[2](http://www.tfd.chalmers.se/~lada/comp_fluid_dynamics/postscript_files/chapter_rhie.pdf)] -- it says that

> We find that the Rhie-Chow interpolation is the same as
>   adding a pressure term, which is proportional to a third [spatial] derivative. [...] In the continuity equation [...] the term is proportional to a fourth-order derivative term [...]

Is there any work on how this *third or fourth order term* actually looks like? Or is there an approximation of the NSE on the PDE level such that a, say, 1st order FVM discretization would directly lead to the Rhie--Chow interpolated scheme?